# Perform a join on two Rails models implementing single table inheritence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, single-table-inheritance

I have three models, let's call them `Product`, `TemplateProduct` and `ReadyProduct`.  There is only one table for these, the `products` table, and both `TemplateProduct` and `ReadyProduct` inherit from the `Product` model.  There is a has_many/belongs_to association between `TemplateProduct` and `ReadyProduct`.  Templates are used to lay out general characteristics for products, Readys are used to customize the products and what are actually made available for view by the customer.  Each `TemplateProduct` has an `id` and each `ReadyProduct` has a `template_product_id` which ties to it's template.

The project is built using Rails 5.

What I want to be able to do is to gather a list of `TemplateProduct`s, then get a count of each templates associated `ReadyProduct`s and do so in such a way that won't hammer the database.  I understand ActiveRecord associations but my SQL is weak and I have only a limited understanding of joins.  I can gather a list of `TemplateProduct`s with a simple `Product.where(conditions`) but I don't know what to once I have this.  For the sake of flexability sake I want to be able to base my `ReadyProduct` count off of this initial collection as sometimes I'll need the additional count and sometimes I won't.  I'm sure there must be a simple way to do this but I haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you just need a mapping of `TemplateProduct` ids to `ReadyProduct` counts, then all you need is:

```rb
TemplateProduct.joins(:ready_products).group(:id).count
```

If you want `TemplateProduct` instances with a baked in `ReadyProduct` count, then you'll need this instead:

```rb
tps = TemplateProduct.joins(:ready_products).select('products.*, COUNT(ready_products_products.id) ready_product_count').group(:id)

tps.first.ready_product_count
#=> 6
```

`ready_products_products` gets defined by Rails, it prefixes the actual table name (`products`) with the model name's "table form" (pluralized, snake case, lower case, `ready_products`), joined with an underscore.

Comment: Use `.left_joins` if you want TemplateProjects with no ReadyProjects in the results.